# Archiving mysql data throwing memory limit issue

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, out-of-memory, archive

I have multiple tables. like table1, table2, table3, etc.

**What is required**:
1. fetch specific row from table1. (for ex: id = 203)
2. fetch all values related to id 203 from table2 (ex: 1,2,3,4,5,6,7....500)
3. again fetch all values of ids from step 2 from table3,table4, etc which have foreign key relation on table2.(millions of rows)
4. Build insert statements for all above 3 steps from result.
5. Insert queries of step.4 in respected tables in archived db with same table names. ie, in short, archiving some part of the data to archive DB.

**How I am doing**:
For each table, whenever got the rows, created insert statement and storing in specific arrays for each table. Once fetched all values till step 3, creating insert statement and storing in array. Then running loops for each separate arrays and executing these queries archived DB. Once queries executed successfully, deleting all fetched rows from main db, then committing the transaction.

**Result**:
So far the above approach worked very well with small DB of size around 10-20mb data.

**Issue**:
For larger number of rows(say more than 5gb), the php is throwing memory exhaust error while fetching rows and hence not working in Production. Even I have increased memory limit till 3gb. I dont want to increase it more.

Alternate solution what I am thinking is, instead of using arrays to store queries, store these queries in files, and then internally use infile command to execute queries to archive DB.

Please suggest how to achieve above issue? once moved to archive DB, there are requirements to move back to main DB with similar functionality.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two keys to handling large result sets.

The first is to stream the result set row by row. Unless you specify this explicitly, the php APIs for MySQL immediately attempt to read the entire result set from the MySQL server into client memory, then navigate through that row by row. If your result set has tens or hundreds of thousands of rows, this can make php run out of memory.

If you're using the `mysql_` interface, use [`mysql_unbuffered_query()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-unbuffered-query.php). You should not be using that interface, though. It's deprecated because, well, it sucks.

If you're using the `mysqli_` interface, call [`mysqli_real_query()`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.real-query.php) instead of `mysqli_query()`. Then call [`mysqli_use_result()`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.use-result.php) to initiate retrieval of the result set. You can then fetch each row with with [one of the `fetch()` variants](http://php.net/manual/en/class.mysqli-result.php).  Don't forget  to use `mysqli_free_result()` to close the result set when you have fetched all its rows. `mysqli_` has object-oriented methods; you can use those as well.

PDO has a similar way of streaming result sets from server to client.

The second key to handling large result sets is to use a second connection to your MySQL server to perform the `INSERT` and `UPDATE` operations so you don't have to accumulate them in memory. The same goes if you choose to write information to a file in the file system: write it out a row at a time so you don't have to hold it in RAM.

The trick is to handle one or a few rows at a time, not tens of thousands.

It has to be said: Many people prefer to use command line programs written in a number-crunching language like Java, C#, or PERL for this kind of database maintenance.

Comment: Thanks Ollie Jones. I am using mysqli interface. But yes, using mysqli_query() functions to query. Will try to use the function you suggested and will see if it works. Also I will use mysqli_free_result function to free memory used. Reason why i used php is because the entire application is in PHP only. And also this process of archiving is also a part of application. What I guessed is while storing rows in php array, its consuming more memory.